# How to reassign an objects "getter" method?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, getter-setter, getter

Lets say theres an object with a getter method.

```
var person = {
 name : "John",
 get title(){
 return "Dr." + this.name
 }
}
>>>person.title
>>>"Dr.John"
```

I would like to reassign the getter method.

```
person.title = function (){return "Mr." + this.name}
```

Is there any way?
Or at least create one dynamically or similar workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
var person = {
 name: "John",
 get title() {
  return "Dr." + this.name
 }
}

console.log(person.title)

Object.defineProperty(person, "title", {
 get: function() {
  return "Mr." + this.name
 }
});

console.log(person.title)
```